# PHP GD: imagecopy() does not work correctly

Tags: php, transparency, gd

Hi I have a list of drawing images and I want to take just the drawing from them with transparent background...

Links to my images currently:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWcRz.png) / [Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGq9Q.png)

```
<?php
$path = 'images/test1.png';

$input = imagecreatefrompng($path);
$width = imagesx($input);
$height = imagesy($input);

$output = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
$transparent = imagecolorallocate($output, 0, 0, 0);

//imagealphablending($output, true);
//imagesavealpha($output, true);

imagecopy($output, $input, 10, 10, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagepng($output,'output.png');
imagedestroy($output);

imagecolortransparent($output, $transparent);
$transparent = imagecolorallocate($output, 0, 0, 0)

?>
```

**Output Image**
[image: Output Image]

**Input Image**
[image: Input Image]

Thank You!

Comment: What does "not work correctly" mean? Is there any error message given?

Answer (score 0):

So it works

```
<?php
$path = 'images/test1.png';

$input = imagecreatefrompng($path);
$width = imagesx($input);
$height = imagesy($input);

$output = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
$transparent = imagecolorallocate($output, 255, 255, 255);
imagecopy($output, $input, 10, 10, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagecolortransparent($output, $transparent);

imagepng($output,'images/output.png');
imagedestroy($output);
?>
```